# Convert "1.5TB", "500MB" into a single unit of file size

Tags: c#, .net, byte

I want to allow a user to enter a file size, using any of the standard suffixes (such as TB, MB, GB)

I'd like to get the value in a way that i can compare them to a folder size.

The idea is to have a program that'll warn if a folder gets above a certain size, with the size dictated by a user-inputted string.

Is there anything built into the .net framework that allows me to parse strings such as `1.5TB`, `400GB`, `1.9GB` and `0.5KB` ?

Comment: Curious, are these base-2 or base-10 prefixes?

Comment: There is nothing built into the BCL, you'll have to roll your own. PowerShell does this.

Comment: @BoltClock, whatever the filesystem uses. I could get clever and treat KB and Kb differently, but that's over-complicating things for my purposes.

Comment: The filesystem uses byte only. Everything else is calculated by the program showing you the file size.

Comment: @Daniel, ok then, whatever is returned by the .net FileInfo type calls (i guess base-2)

Comment: @George: This also only works with bytes: [`FileInfo.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx)

Comment: @George Duckett: [FileInfo.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx) returns the size in bytes.

Comment: @Daniel, ok, i'll go with base 2 then. thanks for the clarification

Comment: @BoltClock those are base-10 base-2 are MiB, TiB, etc.

Comment: @Kolja: I know. Windows, on the other hand, does not agree, and uses KB, MB, GB ... all with base-2, which is why I asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a good candidate for a simple [Interpreter](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternInterpreter.aspx).

Code like this is a simple start, you will need to handle perhaps more cases, and account for differences in casing (`Gb` vs `GB` for example).

You start with a definition for a context and an Expression:

```
public class FileSizeContext
{
    private string input;
    private long output;

    public FileSizeContext(string input)
    {
        this.Input = input;
    }

    public string Input { get; set; }

    public long Output { get; set; }
}

public abstract class FileSizeExpression
{
    public abstract void Interpret(FileSizeContext value);
}
```

Then you define your terminal expression,a nd all of the variants:

```
public abstract class TerminalFileSizeExpression : FileSizeExpression
{
    public override void Interpret(FileSizeContext value)
    {
        if(value.Input.EndsWith(this.ThisPattern()))
        {
            double amount = double.Parse(value.Input.Replace(this.ThisPattern(),String.Empty));
            var fileSize = (long)(amount*1024);
            value.Input = String.Format("{0}{1}",fileSize,this.NextPattern());
            value.Output = fileSize;
        }
    }
    protected abstract string ThisPattern();
    protected abstract string NextPattern();
}

public class KbFileSizeExpression : TerminalFileSizeExpression
{
    protected override string ThisPattern(){return "KB";}
    protected override string NextPattern() { return "bytes"; }
}
public class MbFileSizeExpression : TerminalFileSizeExpression
{
    protected override string ThisPattern() { return "MB"; }
    protected override string NextPattern() { return "KB"; }
}
public class GbFileSizeExpression : TerminalFileSizeExpression
{
    protected override string ThisPattern() { return "GB"; }
    protected override string NextPattern() { return "MB"; }
}
public class TbFileSizeExpression : TerminalFileSizeExpression
{
    protected override string ThisPattern() { return "TB"; }
    protected override string NextPattern() { return "GB"; }
}
```

Then you add a non-terminal expression (this does the bulk of the work):

```
public class FileSizeParser : FileSizeExpression
{
    private List<FileSizeExpression> expressionTree = new List<FileSizeExpression>()
                                                  {
                                                      new TbFileSizeExpression(),
                                                      new GbFileSizeExpression(),
                                                      new MbFileSizeExpression(),
                                                      new KbFileSizeExpression()
                                                  };

    public override void Interpret(FileSizeContext value)
    {
        foreach (FileSizeExpression exp in expressionTree)
        {
            exp.Interpret(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here is the sort of client code:

```
var ctx = new FileSizeContext("10Mb");
var parser = new FileSizeParser();
parser.Interpret(ctx);
Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes", ctx.Output); // 10485760 bytes
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/rundotnet?code=WMGOQ13650

Edits. Changed to MB from Mb (one is officially MegaByte other is MegaBit). Changed int to long to account for large sizes.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: no, there is no built in method.

Long answer: use my converter.

```
public class FileSizeConverter
{
    private static System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo numberFormat;
    private static Dictionary<string, long> knownUnits;

    static FileSizeConverter()
    {
        knownUnits = new Dictionary<string, long>
        { 
            { "", 1L },                                 // no unit is same as unit B(yte)
            { "B", 1L },
            { "KB", 1024L },
            { "MB", 1024L * 1024L},
            { "GB", 1024L * 1024L * 1024L},
            { "TB", 1024L * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L}
            // fill rest as needed
        };

        // since I live in a locale where "," is the decimal separator I will enforce US number format
        numberFormat = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat;
    }

    public long Parse(string value)
    {
        // ignore spaces around the actual value
        value = value.Trim();   

        string unit = ExtractUnit(value);
        string sizeAsString = value.Substring(0, value.Length - unit.Length).Trim();  // trim spaces

        long multiplicator = MultiplicatorForUnit(unit);
        decimal size;

        if (!decimal.TryParse(sizeAsString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number, numberFormat, out size))
            throw new ArgumentException("illegal number", "value");

        return (long)(multiplicator * size);
    }

    private bool IsDigit(char value)
    {
        // we don't want to use char.IsDigit since it would accept esoterical unicode digits
        if (value < '0') return false;
        if (value > '9') return false;

        return true;
    }

    private string ExtractUnit(string sizeWithUnit)
    {
        // start right, end at the first digit
        int lastChar = sizeWithUnit.Length-1;
        int unitLength = 0;

        while (unitLength <= lastChar 
            && sizeWithUnit[lastChar - unitLength] != ' '       // stop when a space
            && !IsDigit(sizeWithUnit[lastChar - unitLength]))   // or digit is found
        {
            unitLength++;
        }

        return sizeWithUnit.Substring(sizeWithUnit.Length - unitLength).ToUpperInvariant();
    }

    private long MultiplicatorForUnit(string unit)
    {
        unit = unit.ToUpperInvariant();

        if (!knownUnits.ContainsKey(unit))
            throw new ArgumentException("illegal or unknown unit", "unit");

        return knownUnits[unit];
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: here's live demonstration: http://rextester.com/rundotnet?code=BQYCB2587 (thanks @Jamiec for the link, really handy to run C# source online)

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find functionality like this in the .NET Framework with a quick Google search, so I guess it's up to you to implement it.

I think splitting the string on numeric values and a dot (or comma, think international) as first part and extracting the KB/MB/etc as second part and parse each part manually will be the way to go.

Comment: Ok, thought something might have been around, no worries.

Comment: @George Is it Regex time? :-) So then you would have TWO problems :-) :-)

Comment: Not sure i get the joke, are you saying you think i'll use Regex and it's overkill/overly complex here?

Comment: @George This would be (nearly) perfect for `Regex`es, BUT, an old quote from Jamie Zawinski (which I support fully, while I'm quite good with Regexes) says: *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.* And you don't even know how many junior programmers come to SO saying "I have this problem and I want to resolve it with Regexes... But I don't know regexes. Can you write me this regex?"... So in the end it's a joke :-)