# Parsing a string double with an M or B at end

Tags: c#

Is there a parse method that understands that for example:

```
1,250,000 = 1.25M
10,000,000 = 10M
10,500,000 = 10.5M
47,600,000,000 = 47.6B
```

In other words, I need to parse 47.6B into a double. I know I can do this by hand,  I am wondering if there is a direct method, say using an `IFormatter`?

Comment: There's no direct method to do this, but you can create custom method using `switch...case` to determine number suffix (depending culture-specific and number base, e.g. base 2 or base 10) and convert it to `double` (`decimal` is more recommended if you have rounding problem).

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such method in .Net framework (and there is no opposite that would format such value).

You'll need to find library that does it or write methods yourself.

Note that K/M may mean either 2^10/2^20 or 10^3/10^6 and could be language specific (again this information is not present in .Net framework as you can see from `CultureInfo.NumberFormat` information)

Answer (score 0):

Some code from here can be adapted:

- http://rextester.com/BQYCB2587
- [Convert "1.5TB", "500MB" into a single unit of file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332669/convert-1-5tb-500mb-into-a-single-unit-of-file-size)

Just specify your own list of recognised decimal "contraction" units:

```
   static FileSizeConverter()
   {
        // decimal "contraction" units 

        knownUnits = new Dictionary<string, long>
        {
            { "", 1L },
            { "M", 1000L * 1000L }, // million
            { "B", 1000L * 1000L * 1000L } // billion (usa)
            // fill rest as needed
        };

        numberFormat = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
    }
```

Then just use it like this:

```
    var converter = new FileSizeConverter();
    Console.WriteLine(converter.Parse("1.25M"));
    Console.WriteLine(converter.Parse("10M"));
    Console.WriteLine(converter.Parse("10.5M"));
    Console.WriteLine(converter.Parse("47.6B"));
```

Use `double` in the parser, or convert from `decimal` to `double` if that's what you need.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Rextester
{

    public class FileSizeConverter
    {
        private static System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo numberFormat;
        private static Dictionary<string, long> knownUnits;

        static FileSizeConverter()
        {
            /*  

            // base2/binary "computer" units

            knownUnits = new Dictionary<string, long>
            { 
                { "", 1L },                                 // no unit is same as unit B(yte)
                { "B", 1L },
                { "KB", 1024L },
                { "MB", 1024L * 1024L},
                { "GB", 1024L * 1024L * 1024L},
                { "TB", 1024L * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L}
                // fill rest as needed
            };

            */

            // decimal "contraction" units 

            knownUnits = new Dictionary<string, long>
            {
                { "", 1L },
                { "M", 1000L * 1000L }, // million
                { "B", 1000L * 1000L * 1000L } // billion (usa)
                // fill rest as needed
            };

            numberFormat = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
        }

        public decimal Parse(string value)
        {
            // ignore spaces around the actual value
            value = value.Trim();

            string unit = ExtractUnit(value);
            string sizeAsString = value.Substring(0, value.Length - unit.Length).Trim();  // trim spaces

            long multiplicator = MultiplicatorForUnit(unit);
            decimal size;

            if (!decimal.TryParse(sizeAsString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number, numberFormat, out size))
                throw new ArgumentException("illegal number", "value");

            return multiplicator * size;
        }

        private bool IsDigit(char value)
        {
            // we don't want to use char.IsDigit since it would accept esoterical unicode digits
            if (value < '0') return false;
            if (value > '9') return false;

            return true;
        }

        private string ExtractUnit(string sizeWithUnit)
        {
            // start right, end at the first digit
            int lastChar = sizeWithUnit.Length - 1;
            int unitLength = 0;

            while (unitLength <= lastChar
                && sizeWithUnit[lastChar - unitLength] != ' '       // stop when a space
                && !IsDigit(sizeWithUnit[lastChar - unitLength]))   // or digit is found
            {
                unitLength++;
            }

            return sizeWithUnit.Substring(sizeWithUnit.Length - unitLength).ToUpperInvariant();
        }

        private long MultiplicatorForUnit(string unit)
        {
            unit = unit.ToUpperInvariant();

            if (!knownUnits.ContainsKey(unit))
                throw new ArgumentException("illegal or unknown unit", "unit");

            return knownUnits[unit];
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] paramList)
        {
            var converter = new FileSizeConverter();
            Console.WriteLine(converter.Parse("1.25M"));
            Console.WriteLine(converter.Parse("10M"));
            Console.WriteLine(converter.Parse("10.5M"));
            Console.WriteLine(converter.Parse("47.6B"));
        }
    }
}
```